# The congruence $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod p^2$ has either $p^2$ solutions or it has at most $p^2-p+1$ solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and $p$ be a prime.

Prove that the congruence $$f(x) \equiv 0 \mod p^2$$ has either $p^2$ solutions or it has at most $p^2-p+1$ solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

---

If  $f(x)$ has $p^2$ roots then we are done and $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod p^2$ has $p^2$ solutions.

But I am stuck with the other part to show that in other cases it has at most $p^2-p+1$ solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

One thing I have observed is that $p^2-p+1 = p^2 - (p-1)$ so we have to eliminate $p-1$ terms from $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

---

Any hints will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $f(a)\not\equiv 0 \bmod p^2$, let $g(x)=f(a+x)$

- If $g(0)\not\equiv 0 \bmod p$ then we are done as $g(b)\not \equiv 0\bmod p$ whenever $b\equiv 0 \bmod p$.
- Otherwise write $g(x)=cp+dx+x^2 h(x)$.

  Then $g(pb) \equiv cp+dbp\bmod p^2$ which is $\not \equiv 0 \bmod p^2$ whenever $db\not \equiv -c\bmod p$.